# To extract texts in selected page(s) from PDF

Tags: python, pdf, extract, pdfminer, pdfminersix

By the use of pdfminer / pdfminer.six, I wish to extract the texts in pdf.

When trying to extract the texts on selected page(s) only, it gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'seek'
# from this line "parser = PDFParser(page_selected)"
```

What's the right way to extract the texts in selected page(s) only?

Here is the code I have:

```
from io import StringIO
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
import pdfminer.high_level as hl

working_folder = "C:\\temp\\"

output_string = StringIO()

with open(working_folder + 'AU.pdf', 'rb') as in_file:

    page_selected = hl.extract_pages(in_file, page_numbers=[1])   # second page

    parser = PDFParser(page_selected)     # error line

    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

    for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

print(output_string.getvalue())
```

Comment: in which line does the error occur?

Comment: @MarcoF., thank you for your comment. from this line "parser = PDFParser(page_selected)".

Comment: looks like an open issue: https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/issues/511 Could be related to the pdf file itself. I can't help much more, sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [dedicated method](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/highlevel.html#extract-text) for text extraction.

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text

working_folder = 'C:\\temp\\'  # wow, r'C:\temp\' breaks code highlighting
file_name = f'{working_folder}AU.pdf'
page_number = 1

page_text = extract_text(file_name, page_numbers=[page_number])
```